# Serializing XmlElement too slow

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

`XmlSerializer` slows down when serializing `XmlElement` which include byte array about 9 MB.
How can I fix it without removing `XmlElement`.

```
   static void SerializeByteArrayToXml(string filePath)
   {
        var array = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var xmlElement = array.SerializeToXmlElement();
        var serializedString = xmlElement.AsXMLString();
   }

    internal static XmlElement SerializeToXmlElement<T>(this T o)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(writer, o);
        }
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
    internal static string AsXMLString<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
        StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

        //This method too slow
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Did you **measure** this? Are you sure your performance-issues are caused by that code? Do you even **have** issues, or is this just some kind of [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes I measured, it takes about an hour. You can also try yourself on files over 9 mb